# UK Citizen - About to Sell Microsoft Store Apps - What is Effectively Connected Income

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom

I am a UK citizen living in the UK and tax based in the UK.
I have created a small Windows Store App which will be sold at about $4.
I will be **very** lucky to get about 250 sales in a year (ie $1,000 per year).
In my Windows Store account it is asking me about 'Effectively Connected Income'.
I have not got a clue what they are on about.

It says the following:

"Certificate of Foreign Status
Numbers in parentheses refer to line numbers on the official IRS W8 forms.
Is the income you receive from Microsoft effectively connected with the conduct of a trade or business in the United States?
Persons/entities must file an annual U.S. income tax return to report income claimed to be effectively connected with a U.S. trade or business (See Effectively Connected Income)"

It then has two radio buttons with 'Yes' and 'No'.

1. What do I click?
2. Do I really have to submit tax forms to the US every year?
3. How on earth do I go about doing that?

Comment: I think the answer is "No", and https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/23043/do-i-have-to-pay-taxes-in-the-us-if-my-online-store-sells-to-us-customers-even-t?rq=1 is a duplicate of this question.